# Infinite series involving $\sinh$ function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Do you know of a way to compute the following infinite series in a closed form expression

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh(n\,\alpha)}\,,
$$

where $\alpha>0$.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a Lambert series and has no closed form that I know of but there is a power series expansion. Let

$$ f(\alpha) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh(n\,\alpha)}
   = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{e^{n\alpha}-e^{-n\alpha}} \tag1 $$

where real part of $\,\alpha>0.\,$ If $\,\alpha = -\log q,\,$ then consider the power series

$$ \frac12 f(\alpha) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n q^n =
  q + q^2 + 2q^3 + q^4 + 2q^5 + 2q^6 + \cdots\tag2 $$

where $a_n$ is [OEIS sequence A001227](https://oeis.org/A001227) 
"Number of odd divisors of n". You can read the sequence entry and it may give further information you can use. Note that the radius of convergence for $q$ is $1$ and the unit circle is a natural boundary. This corresponds to real part of $\alpha>0$.

**EDIT** As the answer by 'Maxim' notes, there exists a closed form using the $q$-digamma function given by 
$\,f(\alpha) = (\psi_{q^2}(1/2)+\log(1-q^2))/\log(q).$
Read the [q-Polygamma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) page for details.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [$q$-digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-gamma_function) $\psi_q(z)$:
$$\psi_q(z) = \frac d {dz} \ln \Gamma_q(z) =
-\ln(1 - q) - \ln(q) \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac 1 {1 - q^{-k - z}}, \\
\sum_{n \geq 1} \operatorname{csch} \alpha n =
2 \sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{k \geq 0} e^{-\alpha n (2 k + 1)} =
2 \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac 1 {e^{\alpha (2 k + 1)} - 1} = \\
-\frac 1 \alpha \left( \psi_{\exp(-2 \alpha)} {\left( \frac 1 2 \right)} +
 \ln \left( 1 - e^{-2 \alpha} \right) \right).$$

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks!